# How do i pass a variable from python to IDL using pidly

Tags: python-3.x, idl-programming-language

I am using pidly, and i would like to transfer a variable from python into IDL

```
import pidly
traj = 'test.traj'
idl = pidly.IDL()
idl('trajfile = "{0}".format(traj)')
```

I just want to be able to use the variable that i have in python in an IDL command.

Comment: What is the output or result of your current code?  Can you provide an example that would show whether or not you've coded it right?

Comment: You may also want to try `idl('trajfile = "{0}"'.format(traj))`